# Calculate, in cm, the length of segment KL

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let ABCD be a rectangle such that AB = $ \sqrt {2} BC $. Let E be a point on the semicircle with diameter AB, as shown in the following figure. Let K and L be the intersections of AB with ED and EC, respectively. If AK = 2cm and BL = 9 cm, calculate, in cm, the length of segment KL.
[image]

I tried to do this question in so many ways (Pythagoras, Similar Triangles...), but I always I found 0=0 or 1=1. Can someone help me? The answer is KL=6 cm.

Comment: Post your efforts, so as to somebody may spot your issue.

Comment: I did Pytagoras in BLC and in ADK and the Cosines Law in KLC, after I did Cosines Law in ALC, but I ever got 0=0, 1=1...

Comment: What information adds the semicircumference?

Comment: @Ripi2 unsure what "information adds the semicircumference" means.

Comment: @coffeemath Point $E$ is in a specific semicircumference, not everywhere else. So, how do you handle this extra-info?

Comment: @Ripi2 Yes I see what you mean. (don't know how to answer your comment/question...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be the projection of $E$ onto $AB$. Set $x=AB$ and $y=EH$. We have then $BC=AD=x/\sqrt2$ and (from the similarity of $EHK$ and $AKD$) $KH=AK\cdot EH/AD=2\sqrt2y/x$, so that:
$$AH=2\Big(1+\sqrt2{y\over x}\Big).$$
Analogously:
$$BH=9\Big(1+\sqrt2{y\over x}\Big)$$
and
$$
\tag{1}
x=AH+BH=11\Big(1+\sqrt2{y\over x}\Big).
$$
From the [Intersecting chords theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersecting_chords_theorem) we also have:
$$
\tag{2}
y=\sqrt{AH\cdot BH}=3\sqrt2\Big(1+\sqrt2{y\over x}\Big).
$$
Dividing $(2)$ by $(1)$ we can find $y/x$ and substituting that into $(1)$ gives $x=17$.

Comment: How can I prove this?

Comment: @Cavalo Prove WHAT exactly?